# How to understand signalR concepts

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, signalr

How to understand how signalR works and its details? There is not much technical documentation out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an episode on channel9 on it worth watching

http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Web+Camps+TV/Damian-Edwards-and-David-Fowler-Demonstrate-SignalR

Answer (score 4):

I haven't watched the channel9 video yet.  But these are some old but good resources on what signalR can do and how to do it.

[Scott Hanselman Blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx)

[HanselMinutes podcast](http://hanselminutes.com/291/damian-edwards-explains-the-realtime-web-for-aspnet-with-signalr)

[The best example app I have seen yet](http://www.amazedsaint.com/2011/11/introduction-ksigdo-knockout-signalr-to.html)